# Как в Panda3D на Python создавать объёмные геометрические фигуры?

Tags: python, 3d, panda3d

Я делаю простое приложение с 3D графикой, в котором я не хочу подгружать какие-либо 3D-модели, а достаточно только геометрических фигур.
Как можно в движке Panda3D создавать такие геометрические фигуры?
Меня интересуют не только простые (пирамида, куб, параллелепипед), а и фигуры с чуть более сложной геометрией. Это фигуры, которые имеют многоугольное основание и "стены", перпендикулярные плоскости построения. Короче говоря, это должны быть примитивы зданий, которые не обязательно всегда имеют форму прямоугольника в основании.

Comment: ну почитайте документацию к Panda3D. от нас вы чего хотите? чтобы мы почитали ее за вас?

Comment: @strawdog, я бы не задавал этого вопроса, если бы там было всё так прозрачно и понятно.

Comment: Это очень широкий вопрос. Посмотрите лучше туториалы по Panda3D

Comment: @Kromster, в туториалах, в основном, описывается работа с загруженными моделями, но не создание своих фигур